# Why is some filesystem space used even though the filesystem is empty?

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage, ext4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ext4: How to account for the filesystem space?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13547/ext4-how-to-account-for-the-filesystem-space)

After googleing a little I find that ext4 reserve 5% for root: [Reserved space for root on a filesystem - why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why), [ext2/3/4 reserved blocks percentage purpose](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41125/ext2-3-4-reserved-blocks-percentage-purpose). And if I use `tune2fs` to set the number of reserved blocks to 0, it will take them back. But I use that code on a 100MB volume and get half of the reserving space, it was 10.5MB, and after setting to 0 the used space became 5.5MB. Why is the used space still not zero?

I used the following command to set the reserved space:

```
tune2fs -m 0 /dev/mapper/truecrypt1
```

Comment: What command did you use to view the reserved space? Remember ext4 needs some room to live in, too. You may want to try `/sbin/tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/truecrypt1` and look at the `Reserved block count` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is still space required for the filesystem's internal usage (superblocks, etc). This is merely the way ext4 works and defines "used space".